# Thread queuing in ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a doubt regarding how `ScheduledExecutorService` works, let's say I have declared an executor like so:

```
private static final ScheduledExecutorService SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
```

And, this is the task I'll be creating to be run when a day passes:

```
SCHEDULED_EXECUTOR.schedule(() -> {
    // do stuff
}, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

If four petitions are received at the same time, do all the timers run and then, only two threads are run in parallel? Or just two timers run in parallel?

Comment: Four petitions? *All* the timers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You configured your ExecutorService to go with two threads. That means that (at maximum) two threads will be serving tasks in parallel.

So when 4 submits come in, they will be "dispatched" to those two threads.

That is all there is to it.